# shell scripting and regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell

```
#!bin/bash
echo enter your password :
read password

passlength=$(echo ${#password})

if [ $passlength -le 8 ];
then
    echo you entered correct  password
else
    echo entered password is incorrect
fi

if [[$password == [a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*]];
then
    echo match found
else
    echo match not found
fi
```

I am not getting what's wrong with this code. If I enter any string as a password, let's say `hello123`, it gives me an error:

> hello123 : command not found

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: What do you expect the pattern to match? If it is a regex, it actually only checks that there is at least one digit. That is, a single-digit input will match.

Comment: i want only a single digit in my string wherever it may be ; at start,middle or at the end.But i dont want more than one digits.so i tried to use [a-z]*[0-9]{1}[a-z]* but it didnt work in shell script but it well worked in Java...why this is so...I am new to shell scripting

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't check anything *other* than the single digit -- that is, "(*#$:5)@(*#@)(*78234782342" will match, because it contains a digit.  The pattern isn't anchored to the beginning and ends of the string, so the two `[a-z]*` parts don't do anything at all.  If you want to match a string with only letters with a single digit somewhere in it (and only lowercase letters around it), use `^[a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*$`.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : your regular expression solved my all troubles...
thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Restricting allowed passwords to only alphabetics and a single digit seems misdirected, though. Why not allow spaces, punctuation, multiple digits? You are forcing your users to make their passwords less secure!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following to make it work cross-platforms with any the bourne shell (/bin/sh) based shell, no bash specific primitives -

```
echo "$password" | grep -q "[a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*"
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ;then
    echo "match found"
else
    echo "match not found"
fi
```

Also feel free to use `quotes` around the variable names. It will save you hours and hours worth of useless debugging. :)

Comment: `[[` does not translate to the `test` program (`[` does) but to a builtin that is a lot more powerful than `test`. Nonetheless, even that will not understand regular expressions -- especially not in the fashion specified in the question.

Comment: @JaypalSingh : say if i want only a single digit in my string and any no of characters followed or preceded by that digit so i use 
[a-z]*[0-9]{1}[a-z]* but still it wont work..

Comment: @omkarsohani : you wrote '... use [a-z]*[0-9]{1}[a-z]* but still it wont work'. Shell reg-exs doen't work like sed or perl reg-exs. Good luck.

Comment: This works, but it doesn't actually answer the question.  It's certainly good to address the real need behind the question, but you should also identify the error, which is what the OP asked for.  In that sense, @bitmask gave a better answer, and also in the sense that they solved the problem within bash without an extra process being called in, and without compromising readability.

Comment: In addition to the point raised by @mc0e, `echo "$password"` is a security problem, as this will lead to the password being shown in plain text when looking at the process list (with `ps`, `top`, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Technically it should give you an error like `[[hello123 : command not found`.

The issue is that `[[$password` is not expanded how you think it is. Bash will first resolve the `$password` variable to what you entered (i.e. `hello123`). This will yield the string `[[hello123` which bash will then try to invoke (and fail, as there is nothing with that name).

Simply add a space () after `[[` and bash will recognise `[[` as the command to run (although it is a builtin).

```
if [[ "$password" == [a-z]*[0-9][a-z]* ]]
then
  ...
```

Comment: say if i enter password as hello2 then it doesnt match but as per your expression it shld match

Comment: I never claimed your regular expression would be interpreted as such. You are merely comparing two strings there. The point is that you have to insert a space between `[[` and its first argument.

Comment: Correct answer, but surprisingly little recognition for it.  Quoting `"$password"` is unnecessary inside `[[ ... ]]` though.

Comment: It would help to be a bit clearer about the confusion between `==` operator and `=~`

Answer (score 1):

The corrected script is below. The errors were:

- `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!bin/bash`
- To read password length, just do `passlength=${#password}`, not 
  `passlength=$(echo ${#password})`
- Always put a space after `[` or `[[`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "enter your password :"
read password

passlength=${#password}

if [[ $passlength -le 8 ]]
then
    echo "you entered correct password"
else
    echo "entered password is incorrect"
fi

if [[ $password == [a-z]*[0-9][a-z]* ]]
then
    echo "match found"
else
    echo "match not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In the bash `[[` construct, the `==` operator will match glob-style patterns, and `=~` will match regular expressions. See [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-g_t_005b_005b-57).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s -p "Enter Password: " password
password_length=${#password}
if [ $password_length -lt 8 -o $password_length -gt 20 ] ;then 
        echo -e "Invalid password - should be between 8 and 20 characters in length.";
        echo ;
    else
        # Check for invalid characters
        case $password in 
            *[^a-zA-Z0-9]* ) 
                echo -e "Password contains invalid characters.";
                echo ;
                ;;  
            * )
                echo "Password accepted.";
                echo ;
                break;
                ;;
        esac
fi
```

More tuned example..

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace line

```
if [[$password == [a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*]];
```

with following

```
if echo "$password" | grep -qs '[a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*'
```

HTH

Comment: @omkar-sohani If it useful, you may upvote it (click at up arrow under question's score) or even accept (click at tick bellow the question's score).

Comment: sorry my reputation is low as i joined stack-overflow yesterday..But certainly your answer helped me.thanks a lot

Comment: omkar, a low reputation doesn't prevent you from upvoting an answer.  In fact, for most of us, that's how we increased our reputations.  Go ahead.  Upvote anything you find useful, and Accept the correct answer.

Comment: @ghoti : users need at least 16 rep-points to upvote, but even w 1 point can do 'Accept'. Good luck to all.

Comment: In bash, you can use a "here string": `if grep -qs '[a-z]*[0-9][a-z]*' <<< "$password"`